# How can I update the Emacs in LispBox?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to update my Emacs (ver. 23.2) in LispBox to the most recent one (ver. 24.3).  I deleted all the previous version of Emacs files with its whole directory, and changed it with version 24.3 Emacs. I also modified Emacs path in "lispbox.bat" file.  But, I failed to load my LispBox.

How can I update my Emacs version in the LispBox?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about LispBox, but the [most recent Emacs release is actually 24.4](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-10/msg00713.html) (October, 2014).

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/andreer/lispbox/) vaguely suggests installing Emacs separately and then using the "no-emacs" version on top.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, and then accept it

Answer (score 1):

20150202 -   22:00
I finally found the way how to update Emacs in LispBox.

1. Download and Extract Files
   1) Download Emacs 24.3 (not 24.4 because it is 64 bit version)
   2) Extract it to the folder where LispBox was installed
2. Copy and Paste two files
   1) Copy two files in the ~/emacs-23.2/site-lisp folder.

   - lispbox.el
   - subdirs.el

   2) Paste those files into the ~/emacs-24.3/site-lisp folder.
3. Modify the lispbox.bat file
   Find the number "23.2", and change it into "24.3".

Now, I can use Emacs 24.3 version in LispBox.